# calculator with 3 text fields, write only on field on focus jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a (probably dumb and easy) question. I have a calculator in Jquery with 3 different text fields and when I use the buttons numbers it write in all three fields at the same time (obviously) cause im using `$("input[type=text]")` in the input declaration, so I know that Im selecting all the input text (and that is exactly what I want to change. I thought about giving and ID to every text field but does that mean that I have to write same function for every ID, that would be very unprof? My question is what is the best way to write only in the input on focus?
Thanks in advance for the help and here is my fiddle:
(maybe it can also help someone :) )

https://jsfiddle.net/2yuve11z/

Comment: how you will know the focused input while you are not focused on? while clicking on one of the buttons, that means that you are not focusing on any of the inputs, right?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutley right and that is also a problem... I quite dont understand how to do it in another way... :/

Comment: so you need to think of a way to mark an input as selected, what about a radio button beside each input? or record the last focused input?

Comment: mmm yes, that sounds good! Im even thinking that I would not need the calculation function, just the numbers to write in the right input type text, Im going to try adding a display:none radio button beside the text fields and running the function on the selectedone! that should solve my issue

Comment: @FernandoLöpez Taha's answer does what you need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with this one:

https://jsfiddle.net/2yuve11z/2/

The logic is:

When an input gets focused, I remove other inputs' `.active` class and add the focused input the `.active` class.Then I only update the one with the `.active` class.

If you want an active input on page load, just add the `.active` class to it.

Comment: Pretty much the same as I wrote but you went further and handled the tidying up after yourself.

Comment: @Taha Paksu and Mauro, that solved the problem at once!!! cheers and thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

By checking which text field is selected you can have your buttons only interact with the one text box

```
 $(function () {
                    focused = '';
        $( "input:text" ).focus(function() {
            focused = this;
        });

        $("input:button").click(function(){
            vlr = $(this).val();
            atual = $(focused).val();
            if(vlr=="C"){
                $(focused).val("");
            }else{
                if(vlr=="="){
                    $(focused).val(eval(atual));
                }else{
                    $(focused).val(atual + vlr);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 Tips**

Change your `<input type="button">` by `<button type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [focus](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus) selector - like: `$("input[type=text]:focus")`